# Why my init block in my class is not triggered when using retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

so from server I will get JSON like this:

```
{
    "success": "1",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "1",
            "url": "5",
            "image": "resources/assets/images/banner_images/1548316546.mitra lakuin.png",
            "type": "category"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "2",
            "url": "5",
            "image": "resources/assets/images/banner_images/1548316605.mobile banner_-02 (1).png",
            "type": "category"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "4",
            "url": "5",
            "image": "resources/assets/images/banner_images/1547010221.gratis ongkir.png",
            "type": "category"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "Customer",
            "url": "5",
            "image": "resources/assets/images/banner_images/1548316659.customer service.png",
            "type": "category"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Banners are returned successfull."
}
```

and I create 2 class in order to convert that JSON to Banner Object.

```
// 1.
class BannerData(val message : String, val success : String, val data : List<Banner>) {}

// 2.

class Banner(id: Int, imageURL: String) {

    @SerializedName("image")
    var imageURL : String
    val id : Int

    init {
        Log.i("testX","triggered")

        this.id = id

        // The code below is used to add percent encoding to URL from server

        val unformattedFullPath = "${Endpoint.lakuin}/$imageURL"
        val formattedFullPath = URLConverterService.addingPercentEncoding(unformattedFullPath)
        this.imageURL = formattedFullPath

    }

}
```

the retrofit interface is like this:

```
    @GET("/app/getbanners")
    fun getBanners(): Call<BannerData>
```

and the interface builder is like this:

```
object RetrofitHandler {

    private val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

    private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .callTimeout(7,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .build()

    private var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Endpoint.lakuin) // default is set to lakuinAPI
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()


    fun <T> getInstance(APIType: Class<T>) : T {
        // baseURL should be change later, if there is more than one API, ex: GoogleMapAPI, LakuinAPI etc
        return retrofit.create(APIType)
    }

}
```

and my problem is .....

as you can see from JSON above, the image URL is not complete, I want to convert the imageURL

from: "resources/blablabla.png"

to be: "http://xxxx.com/resources/blablabla.png"

and I try to convert it inside the init block in the `Banner` class.

but..... it seems the init block in the `Banner` class is never triggered, I try to log it but I can't find in the logcat, that `Log.i("testX","triggered")` never show in the logcat

I actually can create the Banner Object, but the imageURL is exactly same as from JSON, it means the init block is never triggered
[image]

so what went wrong in here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set retrofit to use Gson library as the library for serialize/deserialize objects `addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))`, `Gson` by default is not using constructor or init function instead it `instantiate an object and set its fields via reflection` so i guess your init block just skipped, take a look at `Gson` library to understand if you can configure to not skip `init` function.

Comment: I would use a custom get() block constructing the enriched url on demand. This way you can simply get rid of the init block

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your url in a separate class

```
data class EndPointUrl(val url: String)
```

Create a class and extend `JsonDeserializer` and `JsonSerializer` which will convert your string to `EndPointUrl` and vice versa

```
class EndPointUrlSerializer : JsonDeserializer<EndPointUrl>, JsonSerializer<EndPointUrl> {

    @Throws(JsonParseException::class)
    override fun deserialize(
            json: JsonElement,
            type: Type,
            context: JsonDeserializationContext
    ) = EndPointUrl("${Endpoint.lakuin}/${json.asString}")

    override fun serialize(
            src: EndPointUrl,
            type: Type,
            context: JsonSerializationContext
    ) = JsonPrimitive(src.url)
}
```

Register your serializer in gson object:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder()
                 .registerTypeAdapter(EndPointUrl::class.java, EndPointUrlSerializer())
                 .create()
```

Use this gson object in retrofit:

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                   .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                   .build()
```

Now you can put `EndPointUrl` to your response object:

```
data class Banner(id: Int, imageURL: EndPointUrl)
```